# simpler way to test my simple Rack app?

Tags: ruby, testing

i have a Rack app like this:

```
app = Rack::Builder.new do

    map '/' do
        # ...
    end

    map '/edit' do
        # ...
    end

end.to_app
```

How would i test it without long-tail installation/setup/learn process.

RSpec and minitest are really great, but i do not really want to learn nor setup them.

Is there something i cat just plug in and write/run tests right away in plain Ruby?

I want to write tests as simple as i wrote the app above, without advanced techniques and gotchas.

In KISS I Trust!

Comment: Just so you know, Ruby code is [generally indented two spaces](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout), not four.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try [`Specular`](https://github.com/slivu/specular) + [`Sonar`](https://github.com/slivu/sonar) bundle.

`Specular` is for writing tests anywhere you need them.

`Sonar` is a mock "browser" that communicate to your app, just like `rack-test` does, but with some unique features and simpler workflow.

Using them is as simple as:

```
...
app.to_app

Spec.new do
  include Sonar
  app(app)

  get
  check(last_response.status) == 200
  # etc...
end
puts Specular.run
```

so you put your specs right beside your app and write tests quickly in plain Ruby, without having to learn anything.

see the [full example running at CIBox](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=simpler-way-to-test-my-simple-rack-app.rb&run=true)

(if it does not run automatically, click Run button)

PS: writing Rack apps this way is kinda a pain.

You can try a mapper, like [`Appetite`](https://github.com/slivu/appetite) one.

so your app may look like this:

```
class App < Appetite
  map :/

  def index
    'index'
  end

  def edit
    'edit'
  end
end
```

see the same example but with [app built by `Appetite` here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=simpler-way-to-test-my-simple-rack-app-appetite.rb&run=true)

Comment: mm, looks like something new and promising, playing a bit with it

Comment: awesome! i definitely like it! though initially i thought you just advertise your stuff :)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest? Use [`Rack::Test`](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test#examples) with `Test::Unit`. `gem install rack-test` and run with `ruby filename.rb`

```
require "test/unit"
require "rack/test"

class AppTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Rack::Builder.new do
      map '/' do
        run Proc.new {|env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, "foo"] }
      end

      map '/edit' do
        # ...
      end
    end.to_app
  end

  def test_index
    get "/"
    assert last_response.ok?
  end
end
```

**Update**: RSpec style requested - `gem install rspec`; run with `rspec filename.rb`

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

describe 'the app' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Rack::Builder.new do
      map '/' do
        run Proc.new {|env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, "foo"] }
      end

      map '/edit' do
        # ...
      end
    end.to_app
  end

  it 'says foo' do
    get '/'
    last_response.should be_ok
    last_response.body.should == 'foo'
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, how to run this? also, i prefer the way RSpec define test names. and not sure i want to define a method for each test. this becomes hairy with time.

Comment: Well if you want RSpec style then don't say "RSpec and minitest are really great, but i do not really want to learn nor setup them" lol.  I added an example using RSpec.  You can run `Test::Unit` stuff like regular ruby by just doing `ruby filename.rb`; running rspec tests you do `rspec filename.rb`.

Comment: i meant i ONLY prefer how it defines test names over how `minitest` doing this. that is only what i like at `RSpec`. but generally it looks huge to me and i do not really want to waste time on learning it.

Comment: i just hate sugar magic like `should be_ok`. `be_ok` says nothing to me. `should == 'foo'` is a bit simpler, thus better, but there are tons of that magic sugar that i do not want to remember. i would spend my memory on more important stuff :)

Comment: Yeah I totally understand as I have similar preferences.  In that case you can also write it like `last_response.ok?.should == true`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rack-test but that again entails using minitest/unit test but is the most common way testing Rack apps.